# Child control re-positioned on a auto scroll form when the control is shown

Tags: .net, winforms, autoscroll

I have a form with `AutoScroll` set to true. Some controls on the form are invisible when the form starts, but their location is already set. Once the control turns visible, the position is calculated relative to current `AutoScrollPosition`, which is totally unwanted.

Any idea how to prevent this?

I tried set the position when the control is first shown, as follows:

```
 void OnControlVisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control ctl = (Control)sender;
        if (ctl.Visible)
        {
            ctl.Location = Point.Add(ctl.Location, new Size(this.AutoScrollPosition));
            ctl.VisibleChanged -= OnControlVisibleChanged;
        }
    }
```

It works for some controls, and for others not. I don't know why.
EDIT: it seems that when a control turns visible, the real AutoScrollPosition changes, but the `AutoScrollPosition` property is not updated immediately.

Comment: Controls that have `AutoSize = True` don't seem affected by that.  They place correctly in the panel without any modifications.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks for your effort. I'd love to hear your conclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AutoSize = True` seems to interfere with your code.  I don't know if that's the only point of failure, but this worked in my testing:

```
void OnControlVisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Control ctl = (Control)sender;
  if (ctl.Visible) {
    bool moveOK = true;
    if (ctl.GetType().GetProperty("AutoSize") != null) {
      if ((bool)ctl.GetType().GetProperty("AutoSize").GetValue(ctl, null)) {
        moveOK = false;
      }
    }
    if (moveOK) {
      ctl.Location = Point.Add(ctl.Location, new Size(this.AutoScrollPosition));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: WOW, this is exactly my case! Everything works perfect now. I wouldn't ever think on this. A great thank you sir.